# How to return a value through recursion in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, return-value

I'm trying to iterate through a bunch of uls that could have uls beneath them

```
def go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(child_ul,summary_hash)
  if child_ul.uls.none?
    summary_hash.merge!(child_ul.id => "end of the line")
    eol.push(child_ul.id)
    return eol
  else
    eol = go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(child_ul,summary_hash)
  end
  puts ":"
  return eol
end
```

I never get to the `puts`.  It goes up the ladder all the way to the end of the line child. However, it seems when I return it pushes me all the way out instead of returning back one layer.

Coming from the java world, I would think the return from the function would return into the `eol` variable, but it seems to just die and continue.

Comment: Whether Ruby or Java, don't mutate state in recursive functions.  *JUST DON'T*.  It always makes the code more difficult to reason about.

Comment: @Catnapper i'm confused about what state i'm mutating.  I'm adding items to hashes and arrays.

Comment: I assume that eol is meant to be some kind of state, since it is not initialized in the recursive method, nor is it passed as a parameter to it.  It appears Robustus is also thinking something like this - see his point #2.

Comment: @Catnapper yes I'm sorry that's my fault.  I'm setting eol = [] before the if statement

Comment: initializing eol inside the method wouldn't work either, since every call would have its own `eol`. You're actually mutating `summary_hash`. in my answer you also mutate `eol` which again isn't very nice practice, but you weren't very specific as to instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i would say that there are a couple problems with your code:

```ruby
def go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(child_ul,summary_hash)
  if child_ul.uls.none?
    summary_hash.merge!(child_ul.id => "end of the line")
    # 1. at this point eol is undefined
    eol.push(child_ul.id)
    return eol
  else
    # 2. you define eol here, but you actually call the method
    # recursively again with the same parameters.
    eol = go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(child_ul,summary_hash)
  end
  puts ":"
  return eol
end
```

1. since eol is a local variable it is undefined, so this should
   throw an error (if the `if` statement evaluates to true)
2. eol should either be an instance variable or be supplied via the
   methods parameters. And it isn't really a recursive method if you
   call it with the same arguments. You probably want to
   call it on every of the child_nodes (`child_ul.uls`) and
   merge the results.

A possible result could look like this:
(although i have to say, that mutating parameters in
a recursive algorithm doesn't look pretty good,
if you would be more concise in what you actually need i could supply
a different approach.)

```ruby
def go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(child_ul,summary_hash, eol=[])
  if child_ul.uls.none?
    summary_hash.merge!(child_ul.id => "end of the line")
    eol.push(child_ul.id)
    return eol
  else
    child_ul.uls.each do |ul|
      go_to_child_ul_and_calculate(ul,summary_hash, eol)
    end
  end
  puts ":"
  return eol
end
```